# What is the difference between "AS" and "IS" in an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, keyword

I see Oracle procedures sometimes written with "AS", and sometimes with "IS" keyword.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure TESTUSER.KILLINSTANCE (INSTANCEID integer) **AS**
...
```

vs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure TESTUSER.KILLINSTANCE (INSTANCEID integer) **IS**
...
```

Is there any difference between the two?

---

Edit: Apparently, there is no functional difference between the two, but some people follow a convention to use "AS" when the SP is part of a package and "IS" when it is not. Or the other way 'round. Meh.

Comment: Wouldn't the 2nd always simply point to another procedure that actually implements the functionality?

Comment: In my test, both seemed to work with the exact same body. Dunno about pointing to another proc.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

None whatsover.  They are synonyms supplied to make your code more readable:

FUNCTION f IS ...

CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT ...

Answer (score 59):

One minor difference...

They are synonyms for packages and procedures, but not for cursors:

This works...

```
cursor test_cursor
is
select * from emp;
```

... but this doesn't:

```
cursor test_cursor
as
select * from emp;
```

Comment: Dileep Krishnamurthy's answer completes this

Answer (score 26):

"IS" and "AS" act as a synonym while creating procedures and packages but not for a cursor, table or view.

Answer (score 14):

Here's another difference (in 10g, at any rate)

Given a loose object type:

```
CREATE TYPE someRecordType AS OBJECT
(
   SomeCol VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)
);
```

You can create a `loose` Table type of this object type with either `AS` or `IS`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE someTableType
        IS {or AS} TABLE OF someRecordType;
```

However, if you create this same table type within a package, you must use `IS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SomePackage IS
    TYPE packageTableType IS TABLE OF someRecordType;
END SomePackage;
```

Use of `AS` in the package yields the following error:

> Error(2,30): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:     object opaque

Answer (score 0):

According to [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_procedures.htm)

> The AS keyword is used instead of the IS keyword for creating a
>   standalone procedure.

and considering previous answers,

I guess

`AS` is for stand alone (outside of any block, subprogram, package) entities

and

`IS` is for embedded (within a block, subprogram or package) entities.

.

Comment: That's not really correct; the article you linked to shows you can use AS or IS interchangeably for standalone procedures. Which you use is a matter of taste and/or coding standards. (Personally I do use AS for standalone, and for package declaration; and IS for functions/procedures within packages. But that's just habit.)

Answer (score 0):

The **AS** keyword is used instead of the **IS** keyword for creating a **standalone function**.

[ A **standalone** stored function is a function (**a subprogram that returns a single value**) that is stored in the database.
Note: A standalone stored function that you create with the CREATE FUNCTION statement is **different** from a function that you declare and define in a PL/SQL block or package. ]

For more explanation, [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/function.htm#LNPLS01322)...

Comment: That's not really correct; the documentation you linked to shows you can use AS or IS interchangeably for standalone functions. Which you use is a matter of taste and/or coding standards. (Personally I do use AS for standalone, and for package declaration; and IS for functions/procedures within packages. But that's just habit.)