# PL/SQL. What is the difference between IS and AS for stored procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I have been using `AS` when defining a procedure until i encountered `IS`.

```
create or replace procedure myproc (cnum in customer.custno%type) is  --here
v_name char(20);
v_phone char(10);
begin
......
end myproc;
```

In what cases should i use `is` instead of `as`?

Comment: Already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230348/what-is-the-difference-between-as-and-is-in-an-oracle-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.

> The function body begins with the keyword IS (or AS) and ends with the
>   keyword END followed by an optional function name

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm) for the reference.