# Understanding Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I see the syntax for writing procedure in oracle as below

```
PROCEDURE name [ ( parameter_list ) ]
{ IS | AS }
[ declarative_part ]
BEGIN -- executable part begins
statement; [ statement; ]...
[ EXCEPTION -- executable part ends, exception-handling part begins]
exception_handler; [ exception_handler; ]... ]
END;
```

Can some one guide me when i should  use AS and IS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they're synonymous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "AS" and "IS" in an Oracle stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230348/what-is-the-difference-between-as-and-is-in-an-oracle-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO there is no difference between in using AS and IS Stored procedure

Comment: But the explicit `CURSOR` should be defined using `IS`. will only work,