# Oracle store procedure for insert statement with no IN OUT parameters

Tags: oracle11g

I created a stored procedure for insert statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INSERT
IS /* **WHEN TO USE IS AND AS** */
BEGIN    
declare row_cnt number(30):=0;
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
SELECT * FROM TABLE_C;    
/* process log I created like this */

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line ('process begins : ' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss'));
     TotalUpd := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
UPDATE table2 SET status = 'PROGRESS',row_cnt = TotalUpd  WHERE status is null;
dbms_output.put_line('Total Records Updated. : ' || TotalUpd);
COMMIT;    
end;
COMMIT;    
END;
```

How to execute this stored procedure? I tried like this:

```
Begin
  EXEC TEST_INSERT;
end;
```

Its giving me the PLS-00103 error saying  when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ;

How to execute the stored procedure having insert statement, and how to call this stored procedure in job scheduler?

Comment: Not your main issue, but: [What is the difference between “AS” and “IS” in an Oracle stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230348/266304). Your procedure has several syntax errors, so are you really asking about how to call it, or how to fix it?

Comment: How to fix and call it??

Comment: FWIW, I tend to use "AS" when creating packages, procedures and functions directly, and "IS" when creating functions and procedures within a package, because that's what makes grammatical sense to me; i.e. "create <thing> is <this>" doesn't make linguistic sense, but "<create thing> as <this>" does. Similarly, "<thing> is <this>" makes more sense than "<thing> as <this>". YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXEC` or `EXECUTE` is a SQL*Plus and SQL Developer (and SQLcl...) shortcut for an anonymous block, so you can either utilise that just as:

```
EXEC TEST_INSERT;
```

or create the block yourself without that `EXEC` keyword:

```
BEGIN
  TEST_INSERT;
END;
/
```

You would use the latter in the scheduler as the former is a *client* command, not something the scheduler would recognise.

---

Your procedure has several errors though; you have unnecessary block nesting which is malformed (insert immediately after declare), you aren't declaring `TotalUpd` anywhere but seem to have meant to use that instead for `row_count`, etc.. This will compile at least:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INSERT
IS
  TotalUpd pls_integer;
BEGIN    
  dbms_output.put_line ('process begins : ' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss'));

  INSERT INTO TABLE_1
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_C;    

  TotalUpd := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  UPDATE table2 SET status = 'PROGRESS',row_cnt = TotalUpd  WHERE status is null;
  dbms_output.put_line('Total Records Updated. : ' || TotalUpd);
  COMMIT;    
END; 
/
```

You can use `show errors` to see compilation errors if your client supports that, or query the `user_errors` view. Also, the `dbms_output` calls won't be helpful when you do run this from a scheduler.

Comment: Just an additional note for the OP: you should list the columns you are inserting and selecting, i.e. it should be `insert into table_1 (<column 1>, <column 2>, ...) select <column 1>, <column 2>, ... from table_c;`. That way, should someone add a column to table_c and not table_1 (or vice versa) or a column to both with differing data types (e.g. number and date), your procedure will still work.