# What does "IS" do in Oracle procedures?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, syntax

I want to create a procedure in Oracle; however, any sample that I look on the internet, has an "IS" syntax, which I couldn't find any functionality for it.

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name
    [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

IS
    [declaration_section]

BEGIN
    executable_section

[EXCEPTION
    exception_section]

END [procedure_name];
```

Does anyone know what does "IS" do?

Comment: `IS` just belongs to the syntax and enhances readability. You could just as well ask: "In GROUP BY the word GROUP must always be followed by BY. What is the functionality of BY?"

Comment: Are you asking what goes in [declaration_section] ?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: "BY" does not come alone by itself and "GROUP BY" has a definition and a functionality. The "IS" on the other hand, always comes alone and has a vague functionality.

Comment: @WW: No, I know what happens in [Declaration_Section], I just didn't know what is the use of "IS".

Comment: Slightly related: [What is the difference between “AS” and “IS” in an Oracle stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230348/266304)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IS` is part of [Create procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm) syntax: (can be replace with `AS`)

[image]

It separate the procedure definition from its contents.

The optional declaration section that follows allows you to declare local variables.

Answer (score 4):

`IS`, in this context, tells us (and the compiler) that what follows is the *body* of the procedure. Its absence tells us (and the compiler) that it is merely a declaration (e.g. a forward declaration in a package body):

```
create or replace package body mypkg is

  -- this is just a forward declaration for the procedure
  procedure myproc (id in number);

  -- this is the full definition of the procedure
  procedure myproc (id in number)
  IS
    ..body of myproc..;

end mypkg;
```

In the case of a schema-level procedure, we could (in theory) have a syntax that makes the `IS` optional since there is no need for forward declarations; but (thankfully) the designers of PL/SQL kept the syntax consistent with the in-package syntax so `IS` is still required anyway.