# Oracle stored procedure throwing "not enough values" error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, listagg

This query returns what I want (comma separated values from query)

```
SELECT emp_id, LISTAGG(HOBBIES, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HOBBIES)
FROM employee_list
WHERE emp_id = 123456 
GROUP BY emp_id;
```

Result:

```
Squash,Tennis,Walking
```

Initial data:

```
emp_id   hobbies
-------------------
123456   Walking
123456   Tennis
123456   Squash
000001   Bowling
000002   Tennis
000002   Soccer
```

When I try to convert it to a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMP_ID_FOR_HOBBIES(id NUMBER) 
AS
    x varchar(255);
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_id, LISTAGG(HOBBIES, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HOBBIES)
    INTO x
    FROM employee_list
    WHERE emp_id = id 
    GROUP BY HOBBIES;
END;
```

It returns the following error on compilation

> Error(6,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

I would understand it if it was an insert. What have I done wrong?

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE ... IS`, `IS`, not `AS`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - [really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230348/266304) *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting two column expressions `emp_id` and the `listagg()` result - but you are only selecting into a single variable, `x`.

You need two variables, and list both in the `into` clause, to match the column expressions.

```
...
AS
    l_emp_id employee_list.emp_id%TYPE;
    l_hobbies varchar2(4000); -- has to be big enough
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_id, LISTAGG(HOBBIES, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HOBBIES)
    INTO l_emp_id, l_hobbies
    FROM employee_list
    WHERE emp_id = id 
    GROUP BY emp_id;
...
```

If you really do want a single variable then you need a single column expression - either remove one of them, as you don't really need another copy of the ID:

```
...
AS
    l_hobbies varchar2(4000); -- has to be big enough
BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(HOBBIES, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HOBBIES)
    INTO l_hobbies
    FROM ...
```

or perhaps less likely, concatenate the ID and hobbies into a single string value. The `x` variable will have to be large enough to hold that combined string, of course.

It depends what you plan to do with the values once you have them in local variable(s).

Comment: I'd like to actually use an OUT variable, and have the CSV outputted into that variable. I can update my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're local variables or OUT parameters; you still need the same number if column expressions and `into` targets.

Comment: Yep so i've added an extra out variable as an into target, but that only shows one value, not all three.

Comment: My apolgoies, the above works. Thank you very much for your help.