# PL/SQL cursor creation fails

Tags: sql, plsql

Cursor creation fails in SQL Developer with PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_jobs(d_name varchar2) IS
DECLARE    
    CURSOR curs1
    IS 
        SELECT e.job, d.dname 
        FROM nikovits.emp e 
        JOIN nikovits.dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno where d.dname = d_name;
    rec curs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN curs1;
    LOOP
        fetch curs1 into curs;
        exit when curs1%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(rec.deptno));

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs1;
end;
```

**Error : Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ferid Qenberli - When you create a procedure , you need to omit DECLARE and use AS. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_jobs(d_name varchar2) 
as

    CURSOR curs1
    IS 
        SELECT e.job, d.dname 
        FROM nikovits.emp e 
        JOIN nikovits.dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno where d.dname = d_name;

        rec curs1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN curs1;
    LOOP
        fetch curs1 into curs;
        exit when curs1%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(rec.deptno));
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs1;
end;
/
```

Comment: In that case I get " identifier 'CURS' must be declared" error, and what about IS keyword?

Comment: Curs had to be curs1, and I should select "deptno" as well if i want to print it out

Comment: "rec" variable was earlier pointing to curs instead of curs1 in the original question. Hence the issue. I have fixed in my answer now.

Comment: AS vs IS - you can have detailed answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230348/what-is-the-difference-between-as-and-is-in-an-oracle-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Please use only AS or IS and remove DECLARE keyword.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_jobs(d_name varchar2) IS    
    CURSOR curs1 IS 
        SELECT e.job, d.dname 
        FROM nikovits.emp e 
        JOIN nikovits.dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno where d.dname = d_name;
    rec curs%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN curs1;
    LOOP
        fetch curs1 into curs;
        exit when curs1%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(rec.deptno));    
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs1;
END;
```